# Maximum matching for assigning 2 items

Tags: algorithm, graph

There are N people at a party. Each one has some preferences of food and drinks. Given all the types of foods and drinks that a particular person prefers, find the maximum number of people that can be assigned a drink and a food of their choice.

A person may have several choices for both food and drinks, for example, a person may like Foods A,B,C and Drinks X,Y,Z. If we assign (A,Z) to the person, we consider the person to have been correctly assigned.

How do we solve this problem, considering that there are 2 constraints that we need to handle.

Comment: Hi OP, sorry for the solution I gave you before, it was wrong in my assumption that one food could be shared by 2 people. The revised solution is up where one food cannot be shared (same for drink), hence every person will have a unique combo of food-drink, and no one is sharing any food (or drink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let F be the set of all food there is, D be the set of all drink and P be the set of all people there is.

Build 2 bipartite graphs G and G' such that: for G: the first partite set is P and the second partite set is F, for G': the first partite set is P and the second partite set is D. Do maximal matching on both G and G' separately. Call M the maximum matching on G and M' the maximum matching on G'. M is a list of vertex-pair: (p1, f1), (p2,f2)... where pi and fi are people and food respectively. M' is also a list of vertex pair: (p1,d1), (p3,d3) ...

Now, merge M and M' by merging the pair with the same person: (p1,f1) + (p1,d1) = (p1,f1,d1) and that is the food-drink combo for p1. Say if p2 has a matching with f2 but p2 has no matching in G' (no drink), then ignore it.

A good algorithm for bipartite graph matching is Hopcroft-Karp algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm.